# How can I compare data with File via JUNIT?

Tags: java, junit, junit5

The test which should be executed :

```
@Test
public void Should_Create_List_Of_Racers_And_Put_It_To_Map() throws IOException {

    RacerListPrinter racerListPrinter = new RacerListPrinter();
    Should_Create_List_Of_Racers();
    assertEquals(racerListPrinter.printRacerList(Should_Create_List_Of_Racers()),      );
}
```

where `Should_Create_List_Of_Racers();` :

```
@Test
public List<Racer> Should_Create_List_Of_Racers() throws IOException {

    List<Racer> listOfRacers = new ArrayList<>();
    SortedListOfRacers racerList = new SortedListOfRacers();
    Racer racer1 = new Racer("SVF", "Sebastian Vettel", "FERRARI");
    racer1.setResult("1:04.415");
    listOfRacers.add(racer1);

    Racer racer2 = new Racer("DRR", "Daniel Ricciardo", "RED BULL RACING TAG HEUER");
    racer2.setResult("1:12.013");
    listOfRacers.add(racer2);

    Racer racer3 = new Racer("VBM", "Valtteri Bottas", "MERCEDES");
    racer3.setResult("1:12.434");
    listOfRacers.add(racer3);
```

**My file locates in resources and called `finalResultForTesting.txt` and I need to compare data of
method**

`Should_Create_List_Of_Racers()`

**and the file in this line :**

`assertEquals(racerListPrinter.printRacerList(Should_Create_List_Of_Racers()));`

Output format of `racerListPrinter.printRacerList(List<Racer>)` :

```
1. Sebastian Vettel  | FERRARI                   | 1:04.415
2. Daniel Ricciardo  | RED BULL RACING TAG HEUER | 1:12.013
3. Valtteri Bottas   | MERCEDES                  | 1:12.434
```

Comment: create a list, read the file, tokenize it, create RacerObject from each line, push that racer instance into the list and finally compare the two list.

Comment: What is the output format of `racerListPrinter.printRacerList(List<Racer>)`?

Comment: Also, what is the data format of the `finalResultForTesting.txt`?

Comment: @HariharDas Added output format to my post

Comment: @HariharDas `finalResultForTesting.txt` consist the data of this  `racerListPrinter.printRacerList(List<Racer>)` output, so consist three formatted racers.

Answer (score 0):

Read all the lines of the test result file and pass it as the second argument to the `assertEquals` method.

```
private String readResultFile() throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
    URI uri = this.getClass().getResource("finalResultForTesting.txt").toURI();
    List<String> allLines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(uri));
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    allLines.forEach((line) -> result.append(line).append("\n"));
    return result.toString();
}
```

finalResultForTesting.txt file should be placed in the src/test/resources directory.

[image: Test result file location]

Comment: In this line `URI uri = this.getClass().getResource("src/main/resources/finalResultForTesting.txt").toURI();`I catch java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: I tried to rename like this : `URI uri = this.getClass().getResource("finalResultForTesting.txt").toURI();` too

Comment: Keep the `finalResultForTesting.txt` file in your test/resources directory

Comment: Unfortunately, It didn't help

Comment: I have added a screenshot of how it looks on my system. Is it similar for you?

Comment: Yes, even If I try to change path to java/resources, the same exception..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204834/discussion-between-harihar-das-and-maybe-programmer).

Comment: Try to specify “classpath:finalResultFotTesting.txt” while your file under src/test/resources

Comment: Yet another problem with external resources in tests... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is working solution on java8. I'm expecting that `RacerListPrinter` returns `List<String>`.
Note that I renamed your methods to follow standard camelCase convention.

```
@Test
public void shouldPrintRacerListInCorrectFormat() throws Exception {
    RacerListPrinter racerListPrinter = new RacerListPrinter();

    // yours Should_Create_List_Of_Racers()
    List<Racer> actualRacers = populateRacerList();

    List<String> actualRacersOutput = racerListPrinter.printRacerList(actualRacers);

    List<String> expectedRacersOutput = loadRacerListFromFile("finalResultForTesting.txt");

    assertEquals(expectedRacersOutput, actualRacersOutput);
}

private List<String> loadRacerListFromFile(String fileName) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
    Path path = Paths.get(getClass().getClassLoader()
                     .getResource(fileName).toURI());

    // use try-with-resources in order to ensure stream is closed
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) {
        return lines.collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you want to keep external resources (e.g., the file system) out of your unit tests. You'll always run into problems with files already existing, directories not existing, delays from file flushes, and so on. The [JUnit 4 Temporary Folder](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html) certainly helped with this, but I'd still avoid it whenever I can.

Instead of writing files, have the code under test just write to an `OutputStream`. In real life, this will be a `FileOutputStream`, but in tests this will be e.g., a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. Then your tests can just check the contents of that in-memory stream.

If you write structured data, you can take this one step further: You may have for example a `CsvWriter` or a `PlainTextTableWriter` that format the data. You can test separately that each Writer writes the correct format. When you then test code that writes `Racers`, you don't need to deal with the detail on how they are written (CSV, plain text, JSON, XML, Excel, LaTeX, whatever) anymore; instead you pass a `MockWriter` that just collects the objects the code under test wanted to write. You decouple the code that decides *what* to write from the code that knows *how* to write. If your Writers take [value objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object), these value objects probably implement `equals` anyway, and you can just compare expected to actual objects.

Finally, avoid dependencies between tests. Your `Should_Create_List_Of_Racers_And_Put_It_To_Map` calls `Should_Create_List_Of_Racers`. Both are `@Test` methods; JUnit will call them independently anyway. If you need to share code between tests, put it in its own method, but don't annotate that as `@Test`. Currently, both your tests will fail if `Should_Create_List_Of_Racers` fails, even though `Should_Create_List_Of_Racers_And_Put_It_To_Map` could be perfectly fine.

(Not sure if your code is correct there, AFAIK `@Test` methods need to be void, but you try to return a `List<Racer>`. Make sure your code compiles before posting here.)

Comment: I’m not totally agreed with the first statement regarding external resources. Although this applies mostly to an integration/functional/medium tests, having _expected_ output inside _test resources_ helps you to keep both the test code and _data_ clean, human readable and what’s more important - self documenting. Suppose you’re testing component that outputs _json_ which is best represented in its _native_ format - reviewing such file would give you better understanding then wading through a chain of mocks/interceptors/etc.

Comment: @YuriiJ Hence my comment on separating format / writing and value objects. The writer tests are small enough to keep everything in the test case, anything else should not need to know about JSON details. I find it easier to have everything in one place (the test case), not some test case here and the corresponding test data file in another file in another folder. Just like I prefer Javadoc over documenting in MS Word. But to each their own.